# Show PDF with Javascript and Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm using Phonegap with javascript and jquery. I've created a java servlet, it returns a pdf file. I can get de file correctly in a browser but I can't on Phonegap.

My code is this (javascript):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/MyApp/PDF",
    success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
        alert("pdf OK");
        window.open(data, "_system");
    },
    error: function(data, textStatus, request) {
        alert("pdr error");
    }
```

And here the servlet (this works fine from browser):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
try {
        // Create PDF (this works fine)
    String ruta = getServletContext().getRealPath(reportTemplateUrl);
    InputStream resourceAsStream = new FileInputStream(ruta);
    jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(resourceAsStream);
    jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(findReportData(name)));

    File pdf = new File("output.pdf");
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, new FileOutputStream(pdf));

    // Send PDF
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=output.pdf");
    response.setContentLength((int) pdf.length());
    InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(pdf);
    OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    int bytes;
    while ((bytes = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
        responseOutputStream.write(bytes);
    }
    System.out.println("CREATED!");

} catch (JRException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code is running on iPad with Phonegap and always I get the OK alert. From the iPad's browser I can donwload and read the pdf (I put the URL in the browser as a normal page) and all is OK.

I think the problem is the "data", from javascript, I don't know if I need to save the file first or how to do to show it...

And yes, I need use a servlet and ajax, the PDF is dynamic. I don't mind open it with internal or external browser, but I need to see it.

Thanks!
:)

Comment: you cannot show a PDF with javascript

Comment: and can I get the file and open it with the external browser? That could be a solution for me...

Comment: you need to include a load of cordova javascript SDK files to get the _system thing working - window.open(href, '_system', '_blank');

Comment: Yes, I load cordova when the app starts, and I can open new URLs with safari, but I can't open this data, something is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved this doing a GET call on javascript opening the url on a new browser:

```
window.open("http://.../PDF?id=id&name=name&...", "_blank");
```

Without ajax.

Thanks everyone